# group by time by weekday and id column in python

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to group by 'time' column by weekday along with 'id' column. And here's how I tried and it throws an error:

```
AttributeError: 'Int64Index' object has no attribute 'weekday'.
```

Here's the code:

```
grouped_weekday_id = df_sample.set_index('time', drop=False, inplace=False)
grouped_weekday_id = grouped_weekday_id.groupby([df_sample.index.weekday, 'id']).mean().reset_index()
```

And sample data is as follows:

```
    time            id    64-digits     watts   temp
0   6/26/2017 0:25  1345  9.0072E+15    3.12    71.52
1   6/26/2017 0:25  144   0             1.2     72.96
...
2   6/26/2017 0:25  1152    
3   6/26/2017 0:25  1157    
4   6/26/2017 0:25  617     
5   6/26/2017 0:25  1328    
6   6/26/2017 0:25  913 
7   6/26/2017 0:25  1717
```

Here are the data types for df_sample dataframe.

```
time                datetime64[ns]
id                           int64
64-digits                    int64
watts                      float64
temp                       float64
```

Comment: Can you provide a few more rows and columns? I can't reproduce this error. Are you sure your data is datetime?

Comment: @COLDSPEED I just updated dataset and original dataset is actually huge.

Comment: Do you have any more columns? Did you convert time to date time?

Comment: @COLDSPEED yes, I converted it to date time. Just updated other columns as well.

Comment: Maybe you are just using the wrong dataframe? :) `grouped_weekday_id.groupby([df.index.weekday, 'id'])` -> `grouped_weekday_id.groupby([grouped_weekday_id.index.weekday, 'id'])`

Comment: @CSquare You're right! But even I fixed it, I got another error saying `AttributeError: 'Int64Index' object has no attribute 'weekday'`. My code is as follows: `grouped_weekday_id = grouped_weekday_id.groupby([df_sample.index.weekday, 'id']).mean().reset_index()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, you are assigning grouped_weekday_id to the df_sample dataframe with the time as the index.

Try this:

```
grouped_weekday_id = df_sample.set_index('time', drop=False, inplace=False)
grouped_weekday_id = grouped_weekday_id.groupby(by=grouped_weekday_id.index.weekday).mean().reset_index()
```

I changed the second line of code

Comment: Thanks! I need to group by two columns time and id. Is this a right way to do? `grouped_weekday_id = grouped_weekday_id.groupby([grouped_weekday_id.index.weekday, 'id']).mean().reset_index()`

Comment: Could you try and describe the output of the above and the expected output?

Comment: It was my mistake! No problem.